# C Linked List Bubble Sort Logic Error

Tags: c, linked-list, bubble-sort

Below I have a simple linked list program in C that holds a point and its distance from origin. My problem is that when the sort function is called, it doesn't sort correctly. I have spent quite some time debugging with gdb, but with no luck. I am relatively new to C and dealing with pointers, so if someone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

I was going to post an image of the output, but I don't have enough reputation it seems, so output looks like what is below:

Point: (3,1) - Distance: 3.16228

Point: (4,1) - Distance: 4.12311

Point: (1,1) - Distance: 1.41421

Point: (7,1) - Distance: 7.07107

test.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

typedef struct node
{
    Point p;
    double distance;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insertAtFront(node **start, Point *ip);
void sort(node *start);
void swap(node *a, node *b);
void printList(node *start);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point *insertPoint = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    node *head = NULL;

    point_set(insertPoint,7.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);

    point_set(insertPoint,1.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);

    point_set(insertPoint,4.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);

    point_set(insertPoint,3.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);

    sort(head);

    printList(head);
}

void insertAtFront(node **start, Point *ip)
{
    node *node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node1->p = *ip;
    node1->next = *start;
    *start = node1;
}

void sort(node *start)
{
    Point *tp1 = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    Point *tp2 = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    int swapped;
    node *node1;
    node *node2 = NULL; 
    node *tempNode; 
    double d1;
    double d2;
    if(start == NULL)
        return;
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        node1 = start;
        *tp1 = node1->p;        
        tempNode = node1->next;     
        *tp2 = tempNode->p;     
        d1 = distanceFromOrigin(tp1);
        d2 = distanceFromOrigin(tp2);
        while(node1->next != node2)
        {
            if(d1 > d2)
            {
                swap(node1,node1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            node1 = node1->next;
        }
        node2 = node1;
    }
    while(swapped);
}

void swap(node *a, node *b)
{
    Point *tp;
    *tp = a->p;
    a->p = b->p;
    b->p = *tp;
}

void printList(node *start)
{
    node *temp = start;
    Point *tp = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    printf("\n");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        *tp = temp->p;
        printf("Point: (%g,%g) - Distance: %g\n", point_getX(tp), point_getY(tp), distanceFromOrigin(tp));
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

point.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"
#include <math.h>

void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
    point_set(p,(point_getX(p)+x),(point_getY(p)+y));
}

double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2)
{
    double temp1 = (point_getX(p1) - point_getX(p2));
    double temp2 = (point_getY(p1) - point_getY(p2));
    double temp3 = (temp1*temp1)+(temp2*temp2);
    double dist = sqrt(temp3);
    return dist;
}

double distanceFromOrigin(const Point *p1)
{
    double x = point_getX(p1);
    double y = point_getY(p1);
    double temp = (x*x)+(y*y);
    double dist = sqrt(temp);
    return dist;
}
```

point.h file:

```
#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_

typedef struct Point 
{
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;

void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y);
double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2);
double distanceFromOrigin(const Point *p1);

static inline double point_getX(const Point *p)
{
  return p->x;
}
static inline double point_getY(const Point *p)
{
  return p->y;
}
static inline Point *point_set(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
  p->x = x; 
  p->y = y;
  return p;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Do you mind posting an easy to read version of your problem? Obviously your problem is in the sort function so that you could simply have a simple version of the program with a linked-list of int so that we wouldn't need all your code to try and help you. Also it is not clear from your question directly what you want to achieve but from the code I guess you just want to sort by distance right?

Comment: Yes, I am just sorting by distance after adding the points onto the linked list

Answer (score 1):

The local variable tp in your 'swap'-function is not initialized. Your compiler should warn you about this. Then you access it anyway which is undefined behavior...

Comment: It compiles and runs fine, so I didn't know that was an issue

Comment: Now you know. It is very important to pay attention to compiler warnings when doing any sort of C/C++ programming. Be sure to turn them on.

Comment: Same result after changing

Comment: In your sort function, in your inner while loop, you are always using the values for d1 and d2 that you had computed right before the loop... Another note: You should not malloc local variables like tp1 and tp2 there. Just put them on the stack, by declaring them like "Point tp1;" Then you don't have to free them (which you didn't, anyway... ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense. Unfortunately, the values are still not sorted after putting the d1 and d2 value updates inside the while loop :(

Comment: It is also unclear what exactly you need tp1 and tp2 for. But anyway, you should fire up a debugger, step through the code, and fix the algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When swapping node1 with node1->next, you need to change the next pointer of the previous node that points to node1, or you can swap the data between node1 and node1->next, leaving the next pointers unchanged.

If you were to swap pointers, here is what it looks like before swap:

```
node0->next = node1, node1->next = node2, node2->next = node3
```

and after swap:

```
node0->next = node2, node2->next = node1, node1->next = node3
```

This only works for adjacent nodes. If the nodes were not adjacent, then before swap:

```
nodea->next = node1, node1->next = nodeb
nodec->next = node2, node2->next = noded
```

after swap

```
nodea->next = node2, node2->next = nodeb
nodec->next = node1, node1->next = noded
```